# Avery labels printing PDF 2 columns across then down

Tags: reporting-services

I have followed this documentation http://www.bscichicago.com/documents/CreatingAvery5160MailingLabelsSSRS.pdf 
to print my labels but I did not see where they Spreading Data across 2 columns. PDF rendering is just printing in first column and at the end of the page it will now begin the second column. I wish to print in one column then next column before going to the second row in PDF rendering. Thanks

[image: PDF file results]

Answer (score 0):

Create two identical tables side by side that both point to your data set. On the Detail row of the first table, for the Visibility-Hidden property use the following formula:

```
=iif((RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 2) = 0, True, False)
```

On the Detail row of the second table, for the Visibility-Hidden property use the formula:

```
=iif((RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 2) = 1, True, False)
```

This means the first table will print every odd row and the second table will print every even row, effectively giving you multiple column output but left-to-right first, then down the page, rather than down the page first before moving to the next column like SSRS multi-column reports do.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Let me try your solution. By the way how can I set columns spaces and size so that it can match Avery 5160 Labels format, please? Thanks once again

Comment: Set the column height and width to be the same as your labels and have them set to not auto-expand. It might require some experimentation.

Comment: Thanks once again Chris. Still I am facing the challenges, I tried your solution but the results now are on two pages, Table1 on page1, and table2 on page2. Who Can I do to correct it please?

Comment: Your tables are too wide then - they must fit on your page width, allowing for margins: `Page Width >= 2 * TableWidth + LeftMargin + RightMargin`